# How to output SVG in a Jupyter notebook using jsdom, D3 and IJavascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I'm not strong on frontend development but I have toyed around with a lot of Javascript and D3 recently. Being used to doing scientific analysis in Python using Jupyter Notebooks, I figured it should be possible to use a similar workflow for developing scientific visualizations with D3 using JS code in a Jupiter notebook with a JS kernel. I've looked at [n-riesco](https://github.com/n-riesco)'s [IJavascript project](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript) and it seems promising, but when trying to import D3 the notebook throws an error:

```
// npm install d3
var d3 = require('d3');
```

throws

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I'm guessing this is because there is no DOM in the Jupyter environment ([because Mike Bostock says so](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/issues/10)). In fact if I import `jsdom`, D3 will also import successfully. Awesome! However, now, I cannot select anything because, well... I'm guessing because there is nothing to select in the Jupyter environment.

The things I would like to do is either something like:

```
$$svg$$ = "<svg><rect width=1000 height=1000/></svg>";
var svg = d3.select("svg")
// Beautiful D3 code
```

Or (less cool but also favorable), get a reference to the DOM of some local server, that I can then manipulate by executing code in the notebook.

## Update

With the introduction of [Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/), there is no longer any need to use JavaScript in Jupyter notebooks. Observable is an awesome JavaScript notebook environment that can pretty much do everything. For example, the thing I wanted to do when I asked this question, can be done as simply as:

[image]

Comment: I love Observable too. I do wish you could run it locally—one thing Jupyter notebooks still has going for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me give first a working example (tested on `ijavascript@5.0.19`, `jsdom@9.12.0` and `d3@4.8.0`) and then some clarifications:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
global.document = jsdom.jsdom();

var d3 = require("d3");

var svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .style("fill", "orange");

$$.svg(svg.node().outerHTML);
```

[image: screenshot from 2017-04-20 09-32-53]

This solution:

- uses the DOM provided by [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).
- uses [d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) to create an `<svg>` node and append a `<rect>`
- uses `outerHTML` to get the string representation of the `<svg>` node created in the previous steps
- and finally instructs [IJavascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ijavascript) to return this string to the Jupyter notebook as an SVG result.

In theory, IJavascript could inject javascript code into the Jupyter notebook (to manipulate its DOM), but this code may not run (depending on the security policies of the Jupyter frontend).

---

Since your interest is scientific analysis, you may be interested in a module I published recently: [ijavascript-plotly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ijavascript-plotly).

---

I know this answer skims through many concepts. Please, use the comments below, if you need me to update the answer and explain anything further.

Comment: This works perfectly! Have I understood it correctly if I think: `$$` is an object that stores functions which bind stuff to the Jupyter output cell. We use jsdom to create a DOM that we can write to, and then subsequently read from (using `outerHTML`) and bind html to the output. Can we display the whole DOM?

Comment: @UlfAslak Yes, I think you understood everything correctly.

Comment: @UlfAslak Just one more thing (probably, you already noticed), if you want to tell IJavascript to send an HTML result, you need to use `$$.html` instead of `$$.svg`.

Comment: yep I noticed. This makes it possible to send everything appended to the DOM to the output cell right?

Comment: @UlfAslak In theory yes, in practice you may come across some limitations depending on the frontend. [Hydrogen](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen) for example is limited by the CSP policies in Atom (this means no injected javascript). This may change in the future if Hydrogen starts using webviews.

Comment: `jsdom.jsdom()` doesn't seem to be the way that jsdom gets declared anymore. Can you update those lines?

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to render D3 in Jupyter:

```
var d3 = require("d3");
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var dom = new jsdom.JSDOM("<svg></svg>",{QuerySelector:true});

var svg = dom.window.document.querySelector("svg");

d3.select(svg)
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .style("fill", "orange");

$$.html(dom.serialize());
```